# Add a reference to a class library from another solution (Visual Studio) - best practises?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, class-library

In Solution A there is a project that outputs as a Class Library. In Solution B I need a reference to that library. Currently, I added a reference in Solution B by browsing to a path of Solution A. I am not sure if there is any better solution... my concern is that in the future if Solution A is moved to another folder it will break the Solution B.
I was thinking of copying over dll file directly to Solution B folder but in that case when changes are made on Solution A dll file should be updated manually in Solution B.

Answer (score 2):

One option to make this a bit more sustainable is to have a common directory where you output all your built DLLs and then modify the build process for Solution A to copy built DLLs there (or do this in a separate script). If you expect to expand your usage of this kind of thing, consider using the NuGet package manager. You can set up an internal NuGet server and publish your built DLLs there as a package that Solution B can then consume. That said, this is a lot of work to set up properly, so I wouldn't recommend this unless you are trying to scale this kind of library sharing across many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add the project from Solution A to Solution B, using `Add -> Existing Project` by right-clicking on the solution in the Solution Explorer.